# Modsecurity shared hosting false positive - input form with POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, mod-security

I have simple HTML POST form with text input which is triggering modsecurity deny rule remote file inclusion for following input:

```
https://wa.me/111111111?text=Olá Katarina, tudo bem?
```

The end question mark is problematic. If I delete it - it's not blocked. Basically if the input ends with question mark - is denied. If I add space it will pass.

It's a shared webhosting.
What can I do? Can I do something with headers to prevent being blocked by firewall? (The only thing I have in my mind is to use double URL encoding.

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 429 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 5 at TX:anomaly_score. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs-new/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "93"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"]

ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs-new/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "91"] [id "980130"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 5 - SQLI=0,XSS=0,RFI=5,LFI=0,RCE=0,PHPI=0,HTTP=0,SESS=0): individual paranoia level scores: 5, 0, 0, 0"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "event-correlation"]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="test2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="my_text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should start by contacting the hosting company and talk to them. They know way more about what their security settings are and what can be done

Comment: @M.Eriksson Their response is - firewall needs to be tuned. I am looking for other ways to bypass firewall.

Comment: _"firewall needs to be tuned"_ - Isn't that their firewall? So will they tune it? Even if you can bypass the firewall ()which I doubt you can), it's generally a bad idea (there's a reason why firewalls exist). This sounds like an issue that should be solved at the source (firewall) and not by patching your code.

Comment: Is tagged with PHP as I have problem under apache with modsecurity. And is tagged with javascript as the only solution I can do preventing this is using JavaScript before submitting the form (such as append space). And your comment is super hostile and I will report it

Comment: If you have a problem with Apache and mod_security, how is this problem related to PHP? Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Is the query fragment encoded (`text=Ol%C3%A1%20Katarina%2C%20tudo%20bem%3F`) or literally as shown in the question? Does encoding make any difference?